# Spring amqp - Is there any example to show how to use "sendAndReceive" method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have searched all the websites, but I can't find any example which is clear enough to show how to use `sendAndReceive` method with Spring boot for RabbitMQ.

My question is simple: **How does the `sendAndReceive` work?**

How to achieve that send a message to queue A and wait its response from queue B?
(Another application will handle message from queue A and reply the result to queue B.)

Can anybody provide a simple example? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you looked at the sources?

Comment: Hi, Deinum,
Yes! But I can't figure out that how to configure the "reply queue".
Most articles say that it should be configured in message properties as "reply-to", but how to handle response message?

p.s. I want to send and wait for response with 2 different queues.

Comment: The whole point is you only need to set the reply-to the waiting and handling is done for yu that is the whole point of the `sendAndReceive`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I got following error message while configuring "reply-to" in message properties: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Send-and-receive methods can only be used if the Message does not already have a replyTo property.

Comment: Have you gotten a response?